# Python - Find elements with same id in a dataframe and group together

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a data-frame like this :

```
id  value1 value2
 0     1     1
 1     2     3
 2     1     4
 3     1     5
 4     2     1
```

i want it to be like this :

```
id  value1 value2  count
 0     1     1,4,5   3
 1     2     3,1     2
```

Comment: What datatype is column value2 supposed to be? string?

Comment: Also it looks like you want to group by value1, not by id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with `join` and [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), but is necessary converting column to strings:

```
tups = [('value2', lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))), ('count', 'size')]
df1 = df.groupby('value1')['value2'].agg(tups).reset_index()
print (df1)
   value1 value2  count
0       1  1,4,5      3
1       2    3,1      2
```

Alternative:

```
tups = [('value2', ','.join), ('count', 'size')]
df1 = df['value2'].astype(str).groupby(df['value1']).agg(tups).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could also work:

```
In [2468]: df.value2 = df['value2'].apply(str)

In [2494]: res = df.groupby('value1')['value2'].apply(lambda x:','.join(x)).reset_index()

In [2498]: res['count'] = df.groupby('value1').size().reset_index()[0]

In [2499]: res
Out[2499]: 
   value1 value2  count
0       1  1,4,5      3
1       2    3,1      2
```

Comment: It works perfect. Thanks!